# $gte and $lte on arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have schema

```
{ summaries:
  [
   {
     type: 'temp',
     min: 10,
     max: 40
   },
   {
     type: 'humidity',
     min: 3,
     max: 40
   }
  ],
  thresholds: [
  {
    type: 'temp',
    low: -10,
    high: 40
  },
  {
    type: 'humidity',
    low: 9,
    high: 30
  }
 ]
}
```

This object above is one record in collection.
I want to get records if summaries.type == 'temp' and thresholds.type == 'temp' and summaries.min > thresholds.low

Summaries objects compare with thresholds object must be same type. temp compare with temp, hum compare with hum. Have any summaries object temp that min < any thresholds object temp will be returned

Example:

```
{ summaries:
  [
   {
     type: 'temp',
     min: 10,
     max: 40
   },
   {
     type: 'humidity',
     min: 3,
     max: 40
   }
  ],
  thresholds: [
  {
    type: 'temp',
    low: -10,
    high: 40
  },
  {
    type: 'humidity',
    low: 9,
    high: 30
  }
 ]
}
```

will be returned temp min = 10, threshold low = -10.

```
{ summaries:
  [
   {
     type: 'temp',
     min: 10,
     max: 40
   },
   {
     type: 'humidity',
     min: 3,
     max: 40
   }
  ],
  thresholds: [
  {
    type: 'temp',
    low: 20,
    high: 40
  },
  {
    type: 'humidity',
    low: 9,
    high: 30
  }
 ]
}
```

will be not returned because temp min = 10, threshold temp low = 20 although threshold hum low = 9

Comment: Actually you cant do like that. you shoud use $gt (greater than), or $lt (lower than) and use $aggregate

Comment: Both thresholds and temporary are arrays ? Then which element in the threshold do you want to compare with the temporary array? Basically, can you put up the output structure you want ?

Comment: Yes. Both are arrays. actually are nested 
@Visrozar

Comment: @mandaputtra Can you give me some example ??

Comment: @VũAnhDũng Please reply my other questions as well

Comment: @Visrozar I want to compare thresholds.min ( thresholds.type are temp ) with low value of temporary or threshold.max ( thresholds.type are temp ) with high.

As a thresholds.type == 'temp' AND temporary.low > thresholds.low

Comment: @VũAnhDũng Please add these edits in the question itself

Comment: @Visrozar I just updated for more detail, pls check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query using [**`$expr`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$gt": [
      {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$summaries.min",
          { "$indexOfArray": ["$summaries.type", "temp"] }
        ]
      },
      {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$thresholds.low",
          { "$indexOfArray": ["$thresholds.type", "temp"] }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: I mean not SUM of temporary.low. I want to check if temporary have any low value > thresholds.min wil l return this record

Comment: Does `thresholds` have multiple elements?

Comment: thresholds have only 2 element. [{ low: 20, high: 60, type: 'temp' }, { low: 20, high: 100, type: 'humidity}]

Distinguish by type

Comment: ```{
    "$expr": {
      "$gt": [
        "$temporary.low",
        "$thresholds.min"
      ],
    },
  }```

I tried it but I want to only check temporary on threshold type is temp.

Comment: Sorry. I want to correct my data:
```{
  summaries: [{
    type: 'temp',
    min: 10,
   max: 40,
  }, {
    type: 'humidity',
    min: 30,
   max: 40
  }],
  thresholds: [{
    type: 'temp',
    low: -10,
    high: 40
}, {
   type: 'humidity',
   low: 10,
   high: 30

}]

}```


And want to check in the same type of summaries and threshold

Comment: Please edit your question and explain it widely. With the proper sample document and the output

Comment: I tried and Its working incorrect.
In list response have a record : 
```
{
  "summaries": [
      {
          "type": "temp",
          "min": 31,
          "max": 31
       },
       {
          "type": "hum",
          "min": 54,
           "max": 54,
         }
],
"thresholds": [
       {
       "type": "temp",
          "high": 100,
          "low": 32,
        },
        {
          "type": "hum",
           "high": 100,
            "low": 0,
      }
   ]
}
```
summaries.min < thresholds.low still returned

Comment: Yes you are right. It should be `"$summaries.type" . NOT "$summaries.min" `. Here is the updated fiddle https://mongoplayground.net/p/WhvUh6ftJtl

Comment: Ok. It's working correct. Many thanks bro. 1000 like :D